# Core Data duplicates in table assigned with objectID

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

So I've got tables where I have set an attribute called `name`. The first table grabs the distinct values of name since there can be more than one name of something that is the same. The next table view opens up the duplicates of this particular value.

However, the problem I am having is that the information grabbed from the duplicates only gets from the latest accompanying attribute. So they all point to the same information.

Here is the method grabbing the objects to place in the table.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (NSArray *)allLikePlaces:(id)place {

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[SVAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    [fetch setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@", place];

    [fetch setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"allPlaces error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is the method placing the objects in the table.

**TableView.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    SVAppDelegate *ad = [SVAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
    NSArray *list = [ad allLikePlaces:_place];

    NSManagedObject *obj = list[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

I would to be able to have each of these objects to display their corresponding data and not just the latest record.

I have been trying to implement an `objectID` based implementation with no success. I would greatly appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: I cannot understand what your goal is. Please, explain better what you want to achieve. A sample could be ok.

Comment: @flexaddicted Sorry, the data I select in the table is then outputted to a `UIView`. What is happening is that it is only grabbing the attributes of the last entered duplicate (With the attribute "name") record with the tableview. So for example. The name is UNI, all the cells in that table would then reference the last entered record of the name UNI and not instead their accompanying attributes in the record.

Comment: Your predicate `@"name like %@", place` find all objects where "name" is (more or less) equal to "place", so why are you surprised that all displayed names are equal?

Comment: @MartinR Yes I know I am grabbing the same name attribute, I am not sure how to uniquely associate them with their own data attributes from their records and display them as unique records

Comment: Perhaps you could start by describing all attributes of your entity, show (as flexaddicted said) a sample dataset describing the problem, and explain the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your comment

> The name is UNI, all the cells in that table would then reference the
>   last entered record of the name UNI and not instead their accompanying
>   attributes in the record.

but as Martin says, your predicate finds all objects where the `name` attribute is like `place`. So, all names will be equal.

Now, if you want to create a unique identifier for each object, you should create another attribute like `uuid` (`NSString` type) and populate it with a sort of unique identifier generator at the same time you set the `name` attribute. Apple provides few ways to do it. For example [UUID Strings With Cocoa](http://abizern.org/2012/10/25/uuid-strings-with-cocoa/). Credits goes to **@Abizern**.

About displaying it, just grab when you are running `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. e.g.

```
NSString* uuidString = [obj valueForKey:@"uuid"];
// assign it to whatever UI elements you want
// e.g. cell.detailTextLabel.text = uuidString;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't have time to implement it into my project fully but I couldn't work out how to index with the uuid but set the cell text for something more meaningful (as opposed to randomly generated string IDs). I apologise for the poor explanation, it was rather late at the time.